# getopts for mandatory options for running the script

Tags: bash, getopts

I have 8 options which are mandatory to run the script. However I am unable to pass option values after the first argument. Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash
    usage() { echo "Usage: $0 -f sample_R1.fastq -r sample_R2.fastq -hrp HISAT2_REFERENCE_PATH -g GTF_file -sp KNOWN_SPLICE_FILE -b BOWTIE2_REFERENCE.fasta -rsem_path RSEM_REFERENCE -out_path OUTPUT_PATH -h help" 1>&2; exit 1; }

while getopts ":f:r:hrp:g:s:b:rsem_path:out_path:h" opt; do
    case "${opt}" in
        f) f="$OPTARG"; shift ;; # sample_R1.fastq 
        r) r="$OPTARG"; shift ;; # sample_R2_fastq
        hrp) hrp="$OPTARG"; shift ;;    # HISAT2_REFERENCE_PATH
        g) g="$OPTARG"; shift ;;        # GTF_file
        sp) sp="$OPTARG"; shift ;; # KNOWN_SPLICE_FILE
        b) b="$OPTARG"; shift ;;        # BOWTIE2_REFERENCE
        rsem_path) rsem_path="$OPTARG"; shift ;; #RSEM Reference path
        out_path) out_path="$OPTARG"; shift ;; #Results output path
        h | *) usage ; exit;;
    esac
done

echo "f = ${f}"
echo "r = ${r}"
echo "hrp = ${hrp}"
echo "g = ${g}"
echo "sp = ${sp}"
echo "b = ${b}"
echo "rsem_path = ${rsem_path}"
echo "out_path = ${out_path}"
```

Results

```
f = ./test_data/HBR_Rep1_ERCC-Mix2_Build37-ErccTranscripts-chr22.read1.fastq
r = 
hrp = 
g = 
sp = 
b = 
rsem_path = 
out_path =
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of problems here:

- `getopts` only does single-letter options, and will treat `-hrp` as a shorthand for `-h -r -p` (just like `ls -la` is short for `ls -l -a`). There is a semi-standard format for long options (that start with a double dash, e.g. `ls --color`), but `getopts` doesn't support this.
- `getopts` sets the option variable (`opt` in this case) to the option *not* including the `-`, so your cases should look like e.g. `f)` instead of `-f)`.
- Don't use `shift` in the middle of the `getopts` loop. `getopts` keeps track of where it is in the argument list, and if the argument list gets shifted while it's working on it... things get very confused. Instead, use `shift $((OPTIND-1))` after the loop to get rid of all of the options that've been dealt with.
- You're not actually capturing the option values. That is, when parsing `-f sample_R1.fastq`, `getopts` will set OPTARG to "sample_R1.fastq" but you ignore that and just set `f` to the string "true".
- And finally, you started the option string with ":", which tells `getopts` it shouldn't report errors because you'll take are of that, but you don't. Also, even without that ":", if `getopts` sees an option that isn't on the list, it'll run the loop with `opt` set to "?", so you should check for that and give the usage message in that case.

Here's my take at a corrected version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
    usage() { echo "Usage: $0 -f sample_R1.fastq -r sample_R2.fastq -H HISAT2_REFERENCE_PATH -g GTF_file -s KNOWN_SPLICE_FILE -b BOWTIE2_REFERENCE.fasta -R RSEM_REFERENCE -o OUTPUT_PATH [-h]" 1>&2; exit 1; }

while getopts "f:r:H:g:s:b:R:o:h" opt; do
    case "${opt}" in
        f) f="$OPTARG" ;; # sample_R1.fastq 
        r) r="$OPTARG" ;; # sample_R2_fastq
        H) hrp="$OPTARG" ;;    # HISAT2_REFERENCE_PATH
        g) g="$OPTARG" ;;        # GTF_file
        s) sp="$OPTARG" ;; # KNOWN_SPLICE_FILE
        b) b="$OPTARG" ;;        # BOWTIE2_REFERENCE
        R) rsem_path="$OPTARG" ;; #RSEM Reference path
        o) out_path="$OPTARG" ;; #Results output path
        h | [?]) usage ; exit;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

echo "f = ${f}"
echo "r = ${r}"
echo "hrp = ${hrp}"
echo "g = ${g}"
echo "sp = ${sp}"
echo "b = ${b}"
echo "rsem_path = ${rsem_path}"
echo "out_path = ${out_path}"
```

Note that if you want to give an error message if some options were omitted, you need to check that all of those variables got set. Something like `if [ -z "$f" ] || [ -z "$r" ] ||`...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the "-" in the case statement and so -f should f -r r etc.

Comment: I have edited the script but problem persists in taking in arguments other than the first